# Can I specify certain bits a integer taken in R?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of numbers to load into R for further anaysis. The numbers are small, <128. But there're 4G of such numbers. I would like to load them into a vector. Could I specify certain bits a integer taken in R to reduce memory usage? Breaking down the data was the only choice?

Comment: your data is less than a byte? and you want to pack & store?

Comment: You could represent them as type `raw`, but then you'd lose all the numerical operations; there is only one integer size. Perhaps there are specialized packages for your data, e.g., [Bioconductor snpStats](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/snpStats.html) for representation of SNPs.

Comment: Similar to @Martin's (I guess), I was going to suggest you compute the binary representations of your integers, then store the result using `as.bit` from the `bit` package.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMorgan's advice. It works fine. But it can not be compute directly?

Answer (score 1):

The [ff CRAN package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/) allows you to create vectors with 2,4,8,16 and 32 bit integers (signed or unsigned).